# Multithreaded c++11-ish queue fails on windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I'm not that into multi-threading, so I appreciate any advice.
In my server which is written in producer-consumer multi-threaded style
`queue` is wrapped altogether with its `mutex` and `cv`:

```
template <typename Event>
struct EventsHandle {
public: // methods:
    Event*
    getEvent()
    {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock {mutex};
            while (events.empty()) {
                    condition_variable.wait(lock);
            }
            return events.front();
    };

    void
    setEvent(Event* event)
    {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock {mutex};
            events.push(event);
            condition_variable.notify_one();
    };

    void
    pop()
    { events.pop(); };

private: // fields:
    std::queue<Event*> events;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition_variable;
};
```

and here how it is used in the consumer thread:

```
void
Server::listenEvents()
{
    while (true) {
            processEvent(events_handle.getEvent());
            events_handle.pop();
    }
};
```

and in a producer:

```
    parse input, whatever else
    ...
    setEvent(new Event {ERASE_CLIENT, getSocket(), nullptr});
    ...

void
Client::setEvent(Event* event)
{
    if (event) {
            events_handle->setEvent(event);
    }
};
```

The code works on linux and I don't know why, but fails on windows MSVC13.
At some point exception is thrown with this dialog:
`"Unhandled exception at 0x59432564 (msvcp120d.dll) in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDE1".`
Debugging shows that exception is thrown on this line: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex)` in the `setEvent()` function.

Little googling led me to these articles:
http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598695/Cplusplus-threads-locks-and-condition-variables

I tried to follow them, but with little help. So after this long text sheet my question:
what's wrong with the code, mutex?

**UPDATE**
So... Finally after lovely game named 'comment that line out' it turned out that the problem was in memory management. Event's dctor caused failure.
As conclusion, it's better to use std::unique_ptr<> as mentions [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927690/multithreaded-c11-ish-queue-fails-on-windows#comment38734987_24927690) or use value semantic as advises [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927690/multithreaded-c11-ish-queue-fails-on-windows#comment38735135_24927690) when passing objects back and forth.
And use libraries whenever possible, don't reinvent the wheel =)

Comment: Do you have a single consumer? Otherwise you should make the separate accesses to `getEvent()` and `pop()` synchronized, i.e. put them in one, single synchronised method in the queue. Also (and sorry for the self-advertising), I implemented a proof-of-concept, extremely simple and dumb concurrent queue [here](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/). There's a github link to the source code at the bottom. It would be interesting to see if it works for you.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've just tried to move pop() to getEvent() like: 'Event* tmp = events.front(); events.pop(); return tmp; Nothing changed. And no, I have many producers.

Comment: If you have many consumers, then `getEvent()` and `pop()` should not be separate methods anyway. Say one thread gets an event, and has a pointer to it (all fine, done in a synchronised manner). Then another thread calls pop(). All fine too as far as the 2nd thread is concerned. But now the first thread has a dangling pointer.

Comment: Note: a "consumer" is called a "consumer" because it consumes something. That thing cannot be left for others to try to consume later.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry 0.0 confused words. One consumer - many producers.

Comment: I would use `std::unique_ptr<Event>` instead of raw `Event*`, that would avoid memory management and dangling pointer.

Comment: @Aenry Well, the pointer to an event that the consumer holds could be invalidated when a producer adds events and makes the queue re-allocate. You shouldn't be returning pointers really. Use value semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll try to change the stuff to pass all things by value and move .front() and .pop() in one method. By the way, the link you gave is blocked by the GreatRussianFirewall (trying to find proxy).

Comment: Can you see github? [This is the source code](https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/tree/master/Concurrency/Queue).

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, github is available. Thank you for the link and time you spent. Reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a data race due to a missing mutex in `EventsHandle::pop`.

Your producer thread may push items to the queue by calling `setEvent()`, and get preempted while executing the line `events.push(event)`. Now a consumer thread can execute `events.pop()` concurrently. You end up with two unsynchronized writes on the `queue`, which is undefined behavior.

Also note that if you have more than one consumer, you need to ensure that the element you pop is the same you retrieved earlier from `getEvent`. In case one consumer gets preempted by another between the two calls. This is very hard to achieve with two separate member functions which are synchronized by a mutex that is a member of the class. The usual approach here is to offer a single `getEventAndPop()` function instead, that keeps the lock throughout the operation and get rid of the separate functions you currently have. This might seem like an absurd restriction at first sight, but multithreaded code has to play by different rules.

Comment: Even with a synchronised `pop()`, since the queue returns pointers to data, and not values, a call to `pop()` by one thread could leave another with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Only if one thread is allowed to pop the element that the other retrieved, which is hopefully addressed by my last paragraph.

Comment: But how can you ensure that? It is a queue. You consume and pop whatever happens to be at the front.

Comment: @juanchopanza Either by synchronizing externally (which is quite ugly and somewhat undermines the concept of a thread-safe queue), or by changing the interface to offer a `retrieveAndPop`.

Comment: Exactly. That is the point I was trying to make. The two calls should not be separate in the interface of a concurrent queue.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see. You have a point there. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to change the `setEvent` method to not notify while the mutex is still locked. It depends on the scheduler but the thread waiting to be notified might wake up immediately just to wait for the mutex.

```
void 
setEvent(Event* event) 
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        events.push(event);
    }
    condition_variable.notify_one();
};
```

Comment: Unless you have to care about priority inversions of notified consumers. See [this page for details](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/condvars-signal-with-mutex-locked-or-not/). Also note that many modern implementations are actually smart enough to not wake up a thread blocked on the condition variable if the corresponding lock has not been released yet.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, pop should be integrated in the getEvent().

This will prevent more threads from getting the same event (if pop is not in getEvent then more threads could get the same one).

```
Event*
getEvent()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock {mutex};
    while (events.empty()) {
            condition_variable.wait(lock);
    }
    Event* front = events.front();
    events.pop();
    return front;
};
```